# ExtJS: What are the only required files for grid?

Tags: extjs, extjs5

I have a .net application in which I have used ExtJS grid on only one page. I have included the complete EXT folder in my application that has increased the application size to a considerable amount. I am populating the grid in Ext.onready function and currently the requirement of ExtJS grid is only on a single page. I want to know what are the only required files that I should include in my application so that it does not take any unnecessary space?

Comment: I recommend you another approach. Have a development version and a production version. Use `sencha cmd` to compile the app. It will automatically include only the used files and in addition, it will compress everything to the optimum.

Comment: if you for some reasons don't want to use sencha cmd, the only required files are `build/ext-all.js`, `packages/ext-theme-neptune/build/resources/ext-theme-neptune-all.css` and `packages/ext-theme-neptune/build/ext-theme-neptune.js`

Comment: @JanS: You are right. Add it as an answer and I would be glad to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you for some reasons don't want to use sencha cmd, the only required files are

- build/ext-all.js
- packages/ext-theme-neptune/build/resources/ext-theme-neptune-all.css
- packages/ext-theme-neptune/build/ext-theme-neptune.js